# How I can create instance of an object in another object in js?

Tags: javascript, object, variables

I have an object like,

```
let axis = {
    x: -1,
    y: -1
}
```

and I want to create another object like,

```
let node = {
    //axis object's variable(1) 
    //axis object's variable(2)
    //axis object's variable(3)
}
```

How I can create object like above in javascript?

Comment: You could use object spread: `let node = {...axis}` for a shallow copy. However, *"How to copy an object in JavaScript"* has been asked **plenty** of times. In the future before asking a question, please do some research. Possible duplicate of [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after?

```
let axis = {
  x: -1,
  y: -1
}

let node = {
  x: axis.x,
  y: axis.y
}

console.log(node.x); // prints -1 to the console
console.log(node.y); // prints -1 to the console
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to do such task.

```js
let axis = {
    x: -1,
    y: -1
}

let node = {
    ...axis
}

console.log(node)
```